# When checkbox checks in disable the textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
   <table width="100%" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0" class="data-entry">
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <th>
 <span name="obj1">
 <input type="checkbox"  checked="checked" 
 id="chkOrg1">
<label for="chkOrg1">Ori 1:</label>
</span>
</th>
<td>
 1.   <input type="text" style="width:40px;" 
id="txtOrg1">
</td>
<th>
    <span id="lblDest1">Des 1:</span>
</th>
<td>
 2.     <input type="text" style="width:40px;" id="txtDest1" >
</td>
<th id="thCar1">
Car 1
</th>
<td >     
3. <input type="text" style="width:25px;" id="txtCar1" >
</td>
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<th>
       <span name="obj2"><input type="checkbox" 
checked="checked"  id="chkOrg2">
<label for="chkOrg2">Ori 2:</label></span>
    </th>
<td>
1. <input type="text" style="width:40px;" id="txtOrg2" >
</td>
<th>
    <span id="lblDest2">Dest 2:</span>
</th>
<td>
2. <input type="text" style="width:40px;" id="txtDest2" >
</td>
<th id="thCar2">
    Carr 2
</th>
<td id="tdCar2">
 3.  <input type="text" style="width:25px;" id="txtCar2" >
</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
 ..
 </tr>
<tr>
..
```

...

In that above table contains  checkboxs and textboxes.when checkbox  checked  when disable the first theree textboxes(1,2,3) in the above so how to disable the textboxes please help me how to disable the textboxes please help me.

Comment: u want to make those textboxes readonly/hide??

Comment: Learn 'JavaScript' and optionally 'JQuery' (if you want to do things easily). When you learn those you will know how to do this.

Comment: Any try on your side? Please post what you have tried

Comment: @stevanity How will he learn if not guided in some way? Sure, it may be an easy task for a seasoned programmer such as yourself, but not everyone is a veteran. Most people learn by instruction, some learn by trial and error, and the very few of us are born knowing everything. ;) Why not help him out?

Comment: @GaryHayes the guidance I gave was that, this particular thing can be achieved using JavaScript. If he starts learning JavaScript using some book or just by Googling, he will have an 'AHA!' moment and solve this problem. Without him knowing JavaScript there is no use is us saying stuff like "Write a JQuery listener for the change event or whatever". He will google that alone. And solve the problem. But he will take a long time to get JavaScript and JQuery. But I assume this guy knows it already. Hence my blunt comment. He should know better. Atleast he should try something and post it here.

Comment: I gave -1 for your question because I think typing "help me" three times doesn't make your question more valuable.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('.data-entry input:checkbox').click(function () {
        $(this).closest('td,th').nextAll().slice(0, 5).find('input').prop('disabled', !this.checked)
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6Vu7z/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your updated code. Just place it in your file and check it.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" ></script>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0" class="data-entry">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <span name="obj1">
                    <input type="checkbox"  checked="checked" id="chkOrg1" value="firstcheckbox" class="check_checkbox" onclick="check_status()">
                    <label for="chkOrg1">Ori 1:</label>
                </span>
            </th>
            <td>
                1.   <input class="firstcheckbox" type="text" style="width:40px;" 
                            id="txtOrg1">
            </td>
            <th>
                <span id="lblDest1">Des 1:</span>
            </th>
            <td>
                2.     <input class="firstcheckbox" type="text" style="width:40px;" id="txtDest1" >
            </td>
            <th id="thCar1">
                Car 1
            </th>
            <td >     
                3. <input class="firstcheckbox" type="text" style="width:25px;" id="txtCar1" >
            </td>
            --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            <th>
                <span name="obj2"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"  id="chkOrg2" value="secondcheckbox" class="check_checkbox" onclick="check_status()">
                    <label for="chkOrg2">Ori 2:</label></span>
            </th>
            <td>
                1. <input class="secondcheckbox" type="text" style="width:40px;" id="txtOrg2" >
            </td>
            <th>
                <span id="lblDest2">Dest 2:</span>
            </th>
            <td>
                2. <input class="secondcheckbox" type="text" style="width:40px;" id="txtDest2" >
            </td>
            <th id="thCar2">
                Carr 2
            </th>
            <td id="tdCar2">
                3.  <input class="secondcheckbox" type="text" style="width:25px;" id="txtCar2" >
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            ..
        </tr>
        <tr>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('input:checkbox.check_checkbox').each(function() { 
                var sThisVal = (this.checked ? $(this).val() : "");
                if(sThisVal != ''){
                    $("."+sThisVal).attr('disabled','disabled');
                }

            });
        });

        function check_status(){
            if($('#chkOrg1').is(":checked")){
                $("."+$('#chkOrg1').val()).attr('disabled','disabled');
            }else{
                $("."+$('#chkOrg1').val()).removeAttr('disabled');
            }

            if($('#chkOrg2').is(":checked")){
                $("."+$('#chkOrg2').val()).attr('disabled','disabled');
            }else{
                $("."+$('#chkOrg2').val()).removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Hope this is what you need.